# Python: precision failure in computing acute angle

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, precision

We use the following code for computing acute angle between two lines.

```
def AcuteAngle2(line1,line2):
   ''':: line(x1,y1,x2,y2)'''
   u = (line1[2]-line1[0], line1[3]-line1[1])
   v = (line2[2]-line2[0], line2[3]-line2[1])
   return arccos(abs(dot(u,v)/(norm(u)*norm(v))))
```

It works as expected. For example:

```
>>> AcuteAngle2([0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1])
1.5707963267948966         #in rad = 90 degree
```

However we recently found that it fails in some special cases!

```
>>> AcuteAngle2([0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0])
0.0
```

which is correct, but:

```
>>> AcuteAngle2([0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1])
2.1073424255447017e-08                #failed!
```

which is not correct! it should be 0.0.
**any thought and solution?**

**Update 1:**
Using `Decimal` package as suggested below in the answers may help for some cases. Our problem however stays unsolved as (1) there is lots of code that require amount of time to adapt every part to use `Decimal`. Furthermore, (2) there is significant slow down in the performance. In addition it requires (3) massive changes while dealing with `numpy` arrays. Thus it is not useful for our cases. We are thinking on some sort of decorator etc. without changing things and also keeping `numpy` performance preserved. BTW, some may suggest multiprecision packages such as gmpy etc., note that they require lots of adaptation in the code which is not helpful for our case so.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: So which do you want? Slow and accurate, or fast and inaccurate?

Comment: @MarkRansom If possible having better precision without losing `numpy` performance, with the minimum changes in the available code.

Comment: We have upvoted all the given answers as you will see each addresses nicely part of the problem. Hope someone will give us (i.e., community) a generic and comprehensive solution (or ideas for that) respecting the requirements we pointed out in the question and comments below.

Answer (score 6):

If you care about accuracy, using `arccos` for acute angles is a bad idea. The problem is that for small changes of angle close to 0, cosine of that angle almost doesn't change. For `arccos` situation is reversed - for very-very small changes of cosine angle changes more.

In 2D and 3D a better way is to use `atan2(crossproduct.length,scalarproduct)`

In 2D this becomes `atan2( dx1*dy2-dx2*dy1 , dx1*dy1+dx2*dy2 )`. Please, note that you need not normalize vectors, so there are two improvements:

- no error amplification by `arccos`
- no additional errors by square roots

Comment: The vectors for which the angle is being computed aren't 4D.  The four values in the lists are [x1, y1, x2, y2], where (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are the endpoints of a line segment in 2D.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: In this case everything is much simpler. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for great solution for acute angle. We implemented it and found it works perfectly. However our main problem still remains unsolved as we commented below on @F.J. answer. In brief, we are looking for a solution general with minimum change requirement in the existing code. We presented here a problem we found in acute angle however we are concerned of many other failure in other geometrical functions due to the same roundup error. We upvoted your answer. Hope someone will give us generic tricks which works on other cases.

Comment: The only generic solution coming to my mind (except higher-precision data types) is "evaluate rounding errors in your calculations and select ways which have smaller errors". I doubt there is an easy and generic way :(

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module to increase the precision of your calculations:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

def AcuteAngle2(line1,line2):
   ''':: line(x1,y1,x2,y2)'''
   u = (Decimal(line1[2]-line1[0]), Decimal(line1[3]-line1[1]))
   v = (Decimal(line2[2]-line2[0]), Decimal(line2[3]-line2[1]))
   return arccos(float(abs(dot(u,v)/(norm(u)*norm(v)))))
```

It looks like with the default precision of 28 places you will get the expected answer here:

```
>>> getcontext().prec
28
>>> AcuteAngle2([0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1])
0.0
```

Comment: Thx for the idea. Please also consider "update 1". Any thoughts?

Comment: @Developer, all the `Decimal` changes are inside this function, no changes to the rest of the code should be necessary.

Comment: @MarkRansom We knew that. To explain our problem say we have a package with more than 1000 functions doing geometrical/math (AcuteAngle2 is one example) things. Updating each with similar adaptation using `Decimal` is not our choice due to the reasons explained in 'update 1'.

Comment: @Developer I don't have any ideas that fit your requirements, hope you can find something that meets your needs!

Comment: We appreciate your effort. We will keep this open until someone may come across with a generic solution satisfying our (and possible some others) requirements.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, rounding error is introduced when calculating `dot(u,v)/(norm(u)*norm(v))`. For your test values, the calculation is effectively `2/(sqrt(2)*sqrt(2))`. The computed value for sqrt(2) is rounded to a value slightly larger than the infinite precision value.

```
>>> math.sqrt(2)
1.4142135623730951
>>> math.sqrt(2)*math.sqrt(2)
2.0000000000000004
>>> 2/(math.sqrt(2)*math.sqrt(2))
0.9999999999999998
>>> math.acos(2/(math.sqrt(2)*math.sqrt(2)))
2.1073424255447017e-08
```

The `decimal` module solution by @F.J calculates `2/(sqrt(2)*sqrt(2))` to higher precision. When this value is converted to a float (by arccos), it is rounded to 1.0.

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().sqrt(2)
Decimal('1.414213562373095048801688724')
>>> decimal.getcontext().sqrt(2)**2
Decimal('1.999999999999999999999999999')
>>> 2/decimal.getcontext().sqrt(2)**2
Decimal('1.000000000000000000000000001')
>>> float(2/decimal.getcontext().sqrt(2)**2)
1.0
```

Calculating `2/(sqrt(2)*sqrt(2))` using `decimal` and different precisions highlights another issue.

```
>>> for i in range(10,30):
...   decimal.getcontext().prec=i
...   print i,2/decimal.getcontext().sqrt(2)**2
... 
10 1.000000001
11 0.99999999995
12 1.00000000001
13 1
14 1
15 0.999999999999995
16 1
17 1.0000000000000001
18 1
19 0.9999999999999999995
20 1
21 1
22 0.9999999999999999999995
23 1
24 1
25 0.9999999999999999999999995
26 1.0000000000000000000000001
27 1.00000000000000000000000001
28 1.000000000000000000000000001
29 1
```

The result may be either exactly 1, less than 1, or greater than 1. This can be confusing if you could take `arccos` without rounding to a float first. For the values greater than 1, `arccos` is not defined so the result is a `nan`. If seen this type of rounding error break latitude/longitude calculations when an intermediate value exceeds 1. Just increasing the precision for all calculations, say from float64 to float128, won't fix the problem. It may move the problem to a different set of values, but the rounding errors will still occur.

**Update 1**

There are a couple of other options. You can rewrite your formula as:

```
def AcuteAngle3(line1,line2):
   ''':: line(x1,y1,x2,y2)'''
   u = (line1[2]-line1[0], line1[3]-line1[1])
   v = (line2[2]-line2[0], line2[3]-line2[1])
   return arccos(sqrt(abs(dot(u,v)**2/(dot(u,u)*dot(v,v)))))
```

`AcuteAngle3` avoids your original problem but it is possible that `dot(u,u)*dot(v,v)` is rounded to a value that is slightly smaller in magnitude than the real value and you could try to take the arccos of a value greater than 1. (But just using ROUND_UP or ROUND_DOWN for the entire expression won't work; I tried using different rounding modes in my `decimal` example and some rounding "errors" remained.)

The following function checks for those exceptional occurrences:

```
def AcuteAngle4(line1,line2):
   ''':: line(x1,y1,x2,y2)'''
   u = (line1[2]-line1[0], line1[3]-line1[1])
   v = (line2[2]-line2[0], line2[3]-line2[1])
   temp = sqrt(abs(dot(u,v)**2/(dot(u,u)*dot(v,v))))
   if temp > 1:
      return 0.0
   else:
      return arccos(temp)
```

Computing intermediate values to a higher precision and then rounding down, or selectively rounding towards or away from 0 when calculating each component of your expression, are other possibilities.

Comment: Thx for explanation. Please also consider "update 1". Any thoughts?

Comment: The conversion to `float` is actually explicit in F.J's answer. If the Decimal result is calculated with enough precision, it shouldn't matter if it's less than or greater than 1, it will always round to exactly 1.

Comment: @MarkRansom That is correct. I meant to point out that just increasing the precision for all calculations is not sufficient. You will need to  calculate intermediate values to a higher precision, and then round the intermediate values to a lower precision.